# How to track down a random route? (ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/socket.io/1"):)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting an error in my app, but not sure how anything is pointing to socket.io/1? I have searched my code base and nothing in the code is pointing to this URI?

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/socket.io/1"):
```

How do I track down what is pointing to this non-existent route? Is there a way to print out what code or other controller or view is trying to hit that route?

Comment: check with `rake routes` or `rake routes | grep socket` in your terminal

Comment: `socket.io` is typically used with the websocket plugins - are you using anything like `pusher` or even `nodeJS`? Also, giving some context would be beneficial -- do you have any info on when the error shows?

Comment: Yes we are using nodeJS, but I don't reference a GET on socket.io/1 anywhere in my code? I don't know what is trying to hit that route or why?